# Express.js app child-process scripts are not running on deployed website

Tags: python, node.js, express, iis, child-process

I made a web app using Express.js, that uses some python scripts with child-process.
*Everything is working fine until i deploy the app with IIS*
When the script is about to run in the deployed website, i get this error:

Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: spawn python ENOENT

Comment: you have python installed on your IIS server?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/276494/using-python-scripts-with-iis

Comment: Yeah I tried that one, but the thing is that I don't run the scripts that way. In node I run the scripts as a child process, which runs when the app is not deployed in IIS